Chinese martial arts movie title from my childhood where villain wears a mirror
I am looking for a Chinese kung fu movie that I watched during the 1980s

The movie was in colour and the sound was dubbed in english 
The bad guy was an old man wearing black robes who had a mirror at his chest  to blind the good with the light's reflection and the good guy broke it with nuchaku
There were 4 good guys dressed in brown which are all killed 
There was a flashback scene in black and white where a man (I believe the good guy's brother) fights an army officer wielding a sword,the officer impales the man with the sword after that they both jump in the air and the sword impales both 
I remember dialogue where  the good guy says:my name is Pei Fu from the Jin Wu gymnasium, I am not sure if I spelled the names correctly


The villain in Shaolin Drunk Monkey has a mirror on his chest that blinds opponents, but I don't think it contains anything else (and it's not broken with nunchaku).

Thanks for your time ,i checked shaolin drunk monkey and it's not the movie i am looking
